# Showing $\int_C \ln |x - y| dy = 0$ where $C$ is the unit circle?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, circles, polar-coordinates

I saw it mentioned in a proof that

$$\int_C \ln |x - y| dy = 0,$$

where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and they are both on the unit circle $C$. I'm trying to figure out the calculation but I'm not sure how to show it. First of all I switch to polars and get

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \sqrt{(\cos \theta_x - \cos\theta_y)^2 - (\sin \theta_x - \sin\theta_y)^2} d\theta_y \\ = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \ln (\cos^2 \theta_x - 2 \cos \theta_x \cos \theta_y + \cos^2 \theta_y + \sin^2 \theta_x - 2 \sin \theta_x \sin \theta_y + \sin^2 \theta_y) d\theta_y \\ = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \ln (2 - 2 \cos \theta_x \cos \theta_y - 2 \sin \theta_x \sin \theta_y) d\theta_y \\ = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \ln 2 d\theta_y  + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \ln (1 - (\cos \theta_x \cos \theta_y + \sin \theta_x \sin \theta_y) d\theta_y$$

What steps are needed to get this expression equal to zero?

Comment: Note that $$\cos \theta_x \cos \theta_y + \sin \theta_x \sin \theta_y = \cos(\theta_y - \theta_x)$$ If you are going to work with trig functions, you have to learn to recognize that one and the similar one for sine.

Comment: Your integral is a 'line integral' but $y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. I don't understand your integral !!!.

Comment: @FelixMarin $y = (y_1, y_2)$ is a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and its components are given by the region of integration which is the unit circle. So in polar coordinates, $y$ becomes $(\cos \theta_y, \sin \theta_y)$. $x = (x_1, x_2)$ is a particular fixed point on the unit circle so in polar coordinates it is $(\cos \theta_x, \sin \theta_x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Your last integral is, *indeed*, $\ds{\theta_{x}}$-independent $\ds{\pars{~Why\ ?~}}$. So,

\begin{align}
&{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{1 - \cos\pars{\theta_{y}}}\,\dd\theta_{y} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{2\sin^{2}\pars{\theta_{y} \over 2}}
\,\dd\theta_{y}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{\ln\pars{2\sin^{2}\pars{\theta_{y} \over 2}} +
\ln\pars{2\cos^{2}\pars{\theta_{y} \over 2}}}\,\dd\theta_{y}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta_{y}}}\,\dd\theta_{y} = \bbx{\ds{-\pi\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}

> It cancels the first integral $\ds{{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{2}\,\dd\theta_{x}}$ !!!.

Comment: Ok great thanks!

Comment: @eurocoder Thanks. I'm glad it was useful.